# Install Iptables server

Tags: iptables, debian

I'm new in Linux and I don't know what it refers with Support but I can type some commands like ls, cd, sudo apt-get it always shows up command not found. So, please someone can help me?[terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qof0q.png)

Comment: Unfortunately, Debian is off-topic on [ubuntu.se]. We do, however, have a partner site: [unix.se]. They deal with anything Linux or Unix-related and will be able to answer your question.

Answer (score 0):

If you're running Ubuntu and looking for local firewall configurations, instead of iptables, check out ufw (aka, Uncomplicated Firewall).  It should be installed by default.  To get started, try typing "sudo ufw --help"